# Obter linha de um ficheiro

Tags: php

Estou a ler um ficheiro txt em PHP, e pretendo obter a primeira linha e a ultima linha para poder escrever. Utilizei este codigo para ler todo o ficheiro linha a linha. Mas o que pretendo é so umas linhas.

```
$fp = fopen($fichier,"r");

if ($fp) {

    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $texte = fgets($fp);

        if(strpos($texte,"--") === false ) 
        {} 
        else { 
            $titre = $texte; /
            echo $titre."<br>";
        } 

    }
fclose($fp);}
```

Comment: O quer apenas obter a primeria e a última linha para escrever onde?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguindo o seu próprio exemplo, uma maneira de se fazer o processo seria criar uma função e pegar a linha especifica configurando os argumentos da função.

No caso usei um `array` para definir as linhas que você necessita capturar.

A função retorna um `array`, pois é melhor para você poder organizar.

### Descrição:

`array getLines ( mixed $handle , array $lines)`

- *$handle* Pode ser uma `string` com o caminho do arquivo ou um `resource` retornado de um `fopen`
- *$lines* Deve ser um array com as linhas especificadas

### A função:

```
function getLines($context, $lines) {
    $isResource = false;

    if (is_resource($context)) {
        //Você pode definir um resource ao invés de um "path"
        $fp = $context;
        $isResource = true;
    } else if (is_file($context)) {
        $fp = fopen($context, 'r');
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    $i = 0;
    $result = array();

    if ($fp) {
        while (false === feof($fp)) {
            ++$i;
            $data = fgets($fp);
            if (in_array($i, $lines)) {
                $result[] = $data;
            }
        }
    }

    //Pega última linha
    if ($i !== 1 && in_array('last', $lines)) {
        $result[] = $data;
    }

    if ($isResource === true) {
        //Não fecha se for resource, pois pode estar sendo usada em outro lugar
        $fp = null;
    } else {
        fclose($fp);
    }
    $fp = null;

    return $result;
}
```

### Exemplos:

Lendo linhas 1 e 2 de um arquivo:

```
print_r(getLines('/home/user/test.txt', array(1, 2)));
```

Lendo linhas 3, 6, 11, 12 e 13 de um resource:

```
$res = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
print_r(getLines($res, array(3, 6, 11, 12, 13)));
...
fclose($res);
```

Lendo a primeira e a ultima linha:

```
print_r(getLines('/home/user/test.txt', array(1, 'last')));
```

Answer (score 1):

A 1a linha é fácil, basta usar fgets como vc já está usando. Pra pegar a última linha sem ter que ler todo o arquivo use a classe ReverseFile desta resposta do Stackoverflow em inglês aqui:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234580/read-a-file-backwards-line-by-line-using-fseek

Answer (score 0):

Use a função `file`.

Ex:

```
<?php
$linhas = file('arquivo.txt');
```

Essa função te retorna o conteúdo do arquivo com uma linha por entrada do array. A partir daí é só manipular a linha que você quiser por meio do índice do array e depois reescrever o arquivo com o conteúdo do array (se for o caso):

```
<?php
file_put_contents('arquivo.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $linhas));
```

Comment: Em questão de desempenho do SERVIDOR este método não é muito bom pois pode consumir mais memória que o necessário.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim. se for um arquivo grande, o procedimento pode ser custoso.

Comment: O que eu quero dizer é que se ele deseja a primeira e última linha, o melhor procedimento seria `feof` combinado `fgets` mais um incremento `++$i` para detectar a linha ao qual o usuário solicitou. Assim o gasto seria o mínimo possível.

Comment: Guilherme Nascimento, se o arquivo for pequeno, exemplo, umas 5 linhas, o uso do file() é melhor e o uso do fgets torna-se mais pesado.. Portanto, o que é "certo" ou "errado", depende do caso.